# Random key from dictionary does not recognize it's value when entered as an input

Tags: python, dictionary, random

Trying to do this through dictionary but it is not working. Is there a solution to this?
The assignment is user asked to guess the capital of a randomly chosen country from dictionary. When user writes the answer, it will be turned into value and checked if matches with country key.

```
import random
capitals = {'England': 'London', 'Spain': 'Madrid', 'France': 'Paris'}
rand= (random.choice (list(capitals)))
for i in capitals:
        inp= input("what's is the capital of "+rand+ ":   ")
        if inp.upper()==capitals[i].upper():
            print ("correct")
            break
        else:
            print ("think again")
```

Comment: You’re asking about the capital of `rand` but checking the capital of `i`.

Comment: The `else` should be aligned with the `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration,
`inp.upper()` has the value `PARIS` and `capitals[i].upper()` has the value `LONDON`

what you need to do is, instead of comparing `inp.upper() == capitals[i].upper()`
you should do the following

```
inp.upper() == capitals[rand].upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for that for loop. You should disconnect the number of retries from the size of your capital list.

You can use a while loop instead:

```
import random
capitals = {'England': 'London', 'Spain': 'Madrid', 'France': 'Paris'}
rand= (random.choice (list(capitals)))

while True:
    inp= input("what's is the capital of "+rand+ ":   ")

    if inp.upper()==capitals[rand].upper():
        print ("correct")
        break
    else:
        print ("think again")
```

Comment: you are right, i was just trying to get this basic idea work first and then keep tweaking. i was thinking to change it to while loop. Thank you!